# Trouble building a MIPS compatible C static library

Tags: cross-platform, static-libraries, mips, cross-compiling

I'm trying to build a C static library (.a) that is compatible with a MIPS processor (I'm working in an embedded system).

To do so I tried to execute the following commands (obs: I'm using the mipsel-unknown-elf tool):

```
mipsel-unknown-elf-gcc -o math.o -c math.c
```

*(No erros followed this command)*

```
 mipsel-unknown-elf-gcc -archive -o libmath.a math.o -lm
```

*With this command I got the following error message:*

***cannot find -lm***

***collect2: ld returned 1 exit status***

By getting this message I tried to add a -L/path argument:

```
mipsel-unknown-elf-gcc -archive -o libmath.a math.o -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lm
```

But then I got the following error:

***skipping incompatible /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.a when searching for -lm***

***cannot find -lm***

***collect2: ld returned 1 exit status***

Does anyone knows what's going on?

Comment: I guess you need libm.a static library compiled against MIPS, but you are trying to use libm.a compiled against your host computer (i386)

Comment: Yes I think that to gusbro. But anyone has an idea where I can get libm.a compiled against MIPS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cross compiler distribution should include a MIPS `libm.a`. I just checked and I found several `libm.a` versions in my installation of CodeSourcery `mips-linux-gnu-gcc`. I don't have `mipsel-unknown-elf-gcc` installed, so I can't check that. If the `mips-linux-gnu-` version of `libm.a` is self contained, you might try using that version.