# How to use a library in a MIPS assembly program?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, mips, qtspim

How to use a library(made in c/c++) in a `MIPS` assembly program compiled using `QtSpim`(`MIPS` emulator) ? Using this forum I was able to do this using Intel assembly program by the help of a very talented person @rkhb. This was the solution that he provided:

[how to use a library in masm or more specifcally a .lib file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23550203/how-to-use-a-library-in-masm-or-more-specifcally-a-lib-file/23573879?noredirect=1#23573879)

Now I want to do this same thing in `MIPS` assembly. Now since I am using an Intel processor and using `QtSpim` to run `MIPS` assembly programs, how can I do this while using `QtSpim` ?

Comment: To my knownledge, SPIM and its variants only supports loading assembly language source code, not precompiled executables or libraries.

Comment: @Michael I was of the same view, but then I saw this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16722657/trouble-building-a-mips-compatible-c-static-library and this made me think that it is also possible to do it in SPIM

Comment: That question is not related to SPIM though. Linking object files and libraries written in different languages for MIPS should be no different compared to other platforms. But that's not done at the source code level, so there's no way of doing it with SPIM as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

To call a C compiled function from assembler (or vice versa) the registers must have the following content:

- Registers 4-7 must contain the first 4 arguments
- Using newer C compilers registers 8-11 contain 4 more arguments
- Register 29 must be the stack pointer
- More than 4 or 8 (depending on the compiler) must be stored on the stack (the n-th argument ist located at address (n-1)*4+(register 29) as far as I know; the first 4 or 8 words on the stack may be overwritten by the called routine
- The routine is simply called using "JAL" or "JALR". Some GNU C compiled functions compiled with "-PIC" switch assume a "JALR" instruction with a certain register (28?) so that register contains the address of the function itself.
- When returning from the function register 2 contains the value returned; register 3 the high 32 bits for 64-bit results

If SPIM does not support loading executable files but only source code you may create a statically linked executable file and perform a disassembly.

You may pass the disassembly to the SPIM simulator.

Please note that the "system call" instructions ("syscall" or "syscall #n") have a different meaning in different operating systems. If the library contains system calls than you cannot use library written for Linux in SPIM and vice versa.

--- Edit ---

Library functions compiled with "-pic" switch must be called using "JALR $t9", so register 25 ("t9") holds the address of the function that is called.